# Using UPPER with ElementCollection in JPQL

Tags: eclipselink, jpql, querydsl

Given the following entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Client {

    @Id private
    Long id;
    @CollectionTable
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> accounts;

    // getters and setters here     
}
```

I'd like to find all clients for which any of their account numbers equals (case-insensitive) a search term. Tried the following JPQL with no luck:

```
select c from Client c join c.accounts a where upper(a) = ?1
```

On both EclipseLink 2.4.2 and 2.5 this fails with the following exception:

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select c from Client c join c.accounts a
where upper(a) = ?1]. 
[53, 54] The encapsulated expression is not a valid expression.
```

When changing @ElementCollection to use a full-blown entity for account numbers with an @OneToMany, everything works ok. Also, when removing upper() from the jpql the query runs ok. Eventually we'll want to use QueryDSL for this but currently this querydsl query

```
QClient qc = QClient.client;
StringPath a = Expressions.stringPath("a")
new JPAQuery(em).from(qc).innerJoin(qc.accounts, a).where(a.upper().eq(term)).list(qc)
```

and also this one

```
new JPAQuery(em).from(qc).where(qc.accounts.any().upper().eq(term)).list(qc)
```

fail with similar errors, presumably because they get translated to the same jpql.

How do I change any of these queries to produce the desired results?

Comment: This looks like a EclipseLink bug.

Comment: Confirmed - works using Hibernate.

Comment: Then file a bug http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Bugs Though this might also be something that isn't covered in the JPA specs, and EclipseLink is just stricter